# Show strong topology on the closed unit ball is metrizable

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, metrizability

Let $S$ be the closed unit ball of $B(H)$, the bounded operators on the Hilbert space $H$. I want to show that the relative strong topology on $S$ is metrizable.

**Attempt**: I have already established that the strong topology on $S$ is separable, so we may select a norm-dense sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $S$. Define a metric $d$ on $S$ by
$$d(u,v) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Vert(u-v)x_n\Vert}{2^n}$$
This series converges since $u,v \in S$ and it is easily verified that this is in fact a metric.

Denote the metric topology on $S$ by $\tau_d$ and the strong topology on $S$ by $\tau_s$. We want to show $\tau_d = \tau_s $.

If $u_\lambda \to u$ in $\tau_d$, then it is easily seen that $\Vert (u-u_\lambda)x_n \Vert \to 0$ when $\lambda \to \infty$, hence by density for all $x \in H$ we have $\Vert (u-u_\lambda)x\Vert \to 0$ which means that $u_\lambda \to u$ in $\tau_{s}$. It follows that $\tau_s \subseteq \tau_d$.

If $u_\lambda \to u$ in $\tau_s$, then I want to show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Vert (u-u_\lambda)x_n\Vert}{2^n} \to 0$$

This boils down to interchanging the infinite sum and limit of the net. This makes me thing to use dominated convergence, which will work if we can show that we can replace nets by sequences. So, if we can prove the strong topology on $S$ (or more generally $B(H)$) is first countable, then I will be done. For this, it suffices to find a strong neighborhood basis of the origin

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $x_n$ should be in $H$, I think.

That said, you can estimate the limit directly. Fix $\varepsilon>0$, and $m$ such that $\sum_{n>m}2^{-n}<\varepsilon/4$. Choose $\lambda_0$ such that, for all $\lambda>\lambda_0$, we have $\|(u-u_\lambda)x_n\|<\varepsilon/2$, $n=1,\ldots,m$. Then
\begin{align}
\sum_n\frac{\|(u-u_\lambda)x_n\|}{2^n}
&\leq\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{\|(u-u_\lambda)x_n\|}{2^n}+\sum_{n>m}\frac{2}{2^n}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq \frac\varepsilon2\,\sum_{n=1}^m2^{-n}+\frac\varepsilon2\\[0.3cm]
&<\varepsilon. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Does the rest of the argument seem correct?

Comment: I also agree that the $x_n$ should be in $H$. This seems to be a typo in Murphy then.

Comment: I guess, but you don't provide enough detail to tell. The boundedness of $\{u_\lambda\}$ is essential to the argument, but you only say "by density".

Comment: If we choose the $(x_n)_n$ in $H$, then how do you get the estimate $\Vert (u-u_\lambda)x_n\Vert \leq 2$ for $n > m$, i.e. where does the term $\sum_{n > m} 2/2^n$ come from?

Comment: I think we do need to assume the norm density in the closed unit ball for this, and then we get $u_\lambda x \to ux$ for $x$ in the closed unit ball and by rescaling everywhere.

Comment: Where I use density, I explicitely use the following estimation: Choose $n$ with $\Vert x-x_n\Vert < \epsilon$. Then$\Vert ux - u_\lambda x \Vert \leq \Vert ux - ux_n \Vert + \Vert ux_n - u_\lambda x_n\Vert + \Vert u_\lambda x_n -u_\lambda x_n \Vert \leq 2\Vert x-x_n\Vert + \Vert ux_n- u_\lambda x_n \Vert$ and since $\lim_\lambda  \Vert ux_n- u_\lambda x_n \Vert=0$ this can be made small.

Comment: Well, my 2 comes precisely from the same estimate you used: $$\|ux_n-u_\lambda x_n\|\leq\|u\|\,\|x_n\|+\|u_\lambda\|\,\|x_n\|\leq 1+1=2. $$

Comment: Yes, but if we allow $(x_n)_n$ to be in $H$ as you suggest instead of the unit ball this gives trouble. But with rescaling we can get away with this issue.

Comment: You take $\{x_n\}$ in the unit ball. $u_\lambda x\to0$ if and only if $u_\lambda(tx)\to0$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the confirmation. It was most helpful :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)